# WFS request works in Geoserver but server returns error

Tags: geoserver, leaflet

I'm trying to send a WFS request to my Geoserver but there is something wrong. Here's what I get when I select the JSONP:

http://130.239.57.16:8080/geoserver/beta/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=beta:states&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=text%2Fjavascript

Here's the javascript:

```
    var owsrootUrl = 'http://130.239.57.16:8080/geoserver/ows';

var defaultParameters = {
    service : 'WFS',
    version : '1.0',
    request : 'GetFeature',
    typeName : 'beta:admin>',
    outputFormat : 'text/javascript',
    format_options : 'callback:getJson',
    SrsName : 'EPSG:4326'
};

var parameters = L.Util.extend(defaultParameters);
var URL = owsrootUrl + L.Util.getParamString(parameters);

var WFSLayer = null;
var ajax = $.ajax({
    url : URL,
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback : 'getJson',
    success : function (response) {
        WFSLayer = L.geoJson(response, {
            style: function (feature) {
                return {
                    stroke: true,
                    fillColor: '#FF0000',
                    fillOpacity: 0
                };
            },
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                popupOptions = {maxWidth: 200};
                layer.bindPopup("Popup text, access attributes with feature.properties.ATTRIBUTE_NAME"
                    ,popupOptions);
            }
        }).addTo(map);
    }
});
```

Nothing shows up on the web page, and Firebug shows that the request is made to the server, but the response is:

http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.0.0/OGC-exception.xsd">
      Feature type beta:states> unknown

It seems like the feature type is unknown, but I don't know now to fix it.

Comment: I just tried that URL, and it works for me. Your javascript doesn't actually point to that URL though.

Comment: both urls work for me

Comment: Interesting BradHards -- can  you elaborate? I'm not seeing it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your script.There is a letter "**>**" in your layername.

Its `typeName : 'beta:admin'` and not `typeName : 'beta:admin>'`
(but obviously a layer named "beta:admin" is not published in your geoserver)

for your states-layer it's:

```
var defaultParameters = {
    service : 'WFS',
    version : '1.0',
    request : 'GetFeature',
    typeName : 'beta:states',
    outputFormat : 'text/javascript',
    format_options : 'callback:getJson',
    SrsName : 'EPSG:4326'
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hqmjc4nw/

Comment: totally -- thanks for spotting that Thomas :)  appreciate your time.