# WFS Leaflet script not working

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, wfs

This opens just fine in the browser and the server seems to respond positively to the WFS request, but nothing loads. Can someone help me out here?

```
<html>
<head><title>LeafletTest</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-
0.7.3/leaflet.css"/>
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" content="*">
</head>
<body>
<div id="map" style="width: 1000px; height: 700px"></div>
<script>
var map = L.map('map').setView([64.10418, -20.62987],7);

var owsrootUrl = 'http://130.239.124.215:8080/geoserver/geonode/ows';

var defaultParameters = {
    service : 'WFS',
    version : '1.0',
    request : 'GetFeature',
    typeName : 'geonode:Isleif2015-1>',
    outputFormat : 'text/javascript',
    format_options : 'callback:getJson',
    SrsName : 'EPSG:3057'
};

var parameters = L.Util.extend(defaultParameters);
var URL = owsrootUrl + L.Util.getParamString(parameters);

var WFSLayer = null;
var ajax = $.ajax({
    url : URL,
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback : 'getJson',
    success : function (response) {
        WFSLayer = L.geoJson(response, {
            style: function (feature) {
                return {
                    stroke: true,
                    fillColor: '#FF0000',
                    fillOpacity: 0
                };
            },
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                popupOptions = {maxWidth: 200};
                layer.bindPopup("Popup text, access attributes with feature.properties.ATTRIBUTE_NAME"
                    ,popupOptions);
            }
        }).addTo(map);
    }
});

var mywms = L.tileLayer.wms("http://gis.lmi.is/geoserver/LMI_raster/wms", {
    layers: 'LMI_raster:atlas',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    version: '1.1.0',
    attribution: "<a href='http://gatt.lmi.is'>LMI</a>"
});
mywms.addTo(map);

var overlays = {
    "Isleif2015-1": points,

    };
var layerControl = L.control.layers(null, overlays);
map.addControl(layerControl);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked the syntax of your URL? In the browser console, I see: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`, and trying to access the URL directly, I get the service exception `Feature type geonode:Isleif2015-1> unknown`. I'm able to see the re-projected Iceland tiles (the LMI raster) on the map, but it looks like the WFS ajax request is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look at the GetCapabilities-Response of your Geoserver you will recognize that there is no layer listet.
So either you have no layers published or you don't advertise them to the Capabilities-document and the Layer-Preview:

http://130.239.124.215:8080/geoserver/geonode/ows?Service=WFS&Request=GetCapabilities

http://130.239.124.215:8080/geoserver/web/?wicket:bookmarkablePage=:org.geoserver.web.demo.MapPreviewPage

So it's hard to say if this layer "geonode:Isleif2015-1>" really exists.
As in your other question ([WFS request works in Geoserver but server returns error](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166713/wfs-request-works-in-geoserver-but-server-returns-error)) here also seems to be an unneccessary character ">" in the layername.

Having a look at the Geoserver instance of your other question I saw that there exists a Layer "Isleif2015-1", so perhaps you mixed up your Geoservers?

This one works:

```
var owsrootUrl = 'http://130.239.57.16:8080/geoserver/ows';

var defaultParameters = {
    service : 'WFS',
    version : '1.0',
    request : 'GetFeature',
    typeName : 'Survey:Isleif2015-1',
    outputFormat : 'text/javascript',
    format_options : 'callback:getJson',
    SrsName : 'EPSG:4326',
    MaxFeatures: 200
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fss5x8sa/